# How to create this file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tags: postgresql

By mistake, I deleted the `.s.PGSQL.5432` file in folder `/var/run/postgresql`

because of that , I cant able to add server in pgAdmin , Instead i am getting error like below

```
An error has occurred:

Error connecting to the server: could not connect to server:
No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting 
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

please, someone help me to resolve this problem

Comment: This question belongs on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: Or possibly [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix would be to restart the PostgreSQL daemon.  It should recreate the socket file on startup.

Reloading the configuration file might also cause the socket file to be recreated.  You can do this from a shell:

```
pg_ctl reload
```

Or from an existing PostgreSQL connection that has superuser privileges:

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

Comment: another workaround would be to connect via 127.0.0.1 or one the machines other ip-adresses, if any.

Comment: @wildplasser Yes, but if the server is being used for anything else (such as for a web application) then it's likely that incoming connections to the server are currently failing and those services will therefore be failing to operate correctly. One could run around updating all of their config files, or just bite the bullet and restart the daemon.

Comment: I know that, but it could be a way if the OP has no super-ninja powers on the machine (I fear that he does have them, since he managed to delete the socket ...)